# How do I change my folder structure using Rar.exe

Tags: rar, winrar

I am building a rar command in code.  I get a share and folder in a database call (*\\BUServer1\Share01$\IHDEV01*) and then I get a list of subfolders and extensions that I want to archive (*FLATFILES*.dbf"*)  I concatenate the two as seen in the command below.

I only point this out because I build this on the fly with unknown values.  My problem is that when the archive is opened an IHDEV01 folder is at the top of the archive and everything else is contained within (see image below). My requirements are to keep everything as is but remove the IHDEV01 from being at the top of the archive.  I have tried passing -ep1 as a command argument which does remove the IHDEV01 folder but it also removes the folder structure below IHDEV01.  I thought about mapping the share and folder to a letter but the process that carries out these archiving jobs could potentially be called more than once on different customers.  Is there a simple solution that I am not seeing?

```
rar.exe a -r -ed  -s -sfx "C:\Sigma\Applications\Development\ BackupService\1.0.4016\bin\Data\IHDEV01\IHDEV01_DatabaseFiles" -hpmypassword -v2048m "\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\FLATFILES\*.dbf" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\FLATFILES\ASMAIL*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\comm\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\Forms\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\Integ\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\PCX\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\Txt\*.ids" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\APPS\mvr\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\log\*.log" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\dat\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\wintam\winrpts\*.fxp" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\misc\winrpts\*.prg" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\as_flags\*.*" 
"\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\as_desk\*.*"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the switch `-ep1` to remove the base directory path `\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\FLATFILES\` and use the switch `-apFLATFILES` to add this directory path to each file compressed into the SFX archive file.

So the command line is:

```
rar.exe a -apFLATFILES -ed -ep1 -hpmypassword -r -s -sfx -v2048m "C:\Sigma\Applications\Development\BackupService\1.0.4016\bin\Data\IHDEV01\IHDEV01_DatabaseFiles" "\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\FLATFILES\*.dbf"
```

**Example:**

The directory `\\BUServer1\SHARE01$\IHDEV01\FLATFILES` contains:

- **Subdirectory 1**

  - **Subfolder 1**

    - File_1-1.dbf
  - **Subfolder 2**

    - File_1_2.dbf
  - File_1.dbf
- **Subdirectory 2**

  - File_2.dbf
- File.dbf

The created RAR SFX archive file `C:\Sigma\Applications\Development\BackupService\1.0.4016\bin\Data\IHDEV01\IHDEV01_DatabaseFiles.exe` contains in this case:

```
FLATFILES\File.dbf
FLATFILES\Subdirectory 1\Subfolder 1\File_1-1.dbf
FLATFILES\Subdirectory 1\Subfolder 2\File_1-2.dbf
FLATFILES\Subdirectory 1\File_1.dbf
FLATFILES\Subdirectory 2\File_2.dbf
```